# how to find character in string in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm new to MIPS assembly, I'm trying to make a program that finds the character just before `"?"`

However, for example when I enter input like `" abc?"`, output is `"c?"`. I can't find my mistake.

code is here:

```
.data 

buffer: .space 1024
.text
.globl main

main:

la $a0,buffer 
li $v0,8 
syscall 


la $t1,buffer 


loop: 
lb $t2,($t1) 
beq $t2,'?',loop1 
add $t1,$t1,1 
j loop

loop1:
sub $t1,$t1,1
move $a0,$t1 
li $v0,4 
syscall 

li $v0,10 
syscall
```

Comment: Is the problem that you're outputting the question mark in addition to 'c'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `print_string` syscall, which won't stop until it finds a NUL terminator.

If you only want to print a single character it would be better to use the `print_character` syscall (11); i.e. replace

```
move $a0,$t1 
li $v0,4
```

with

```
lb $a0,($t1)
li $v0,11
```